# Need to submit forms twice to be processed?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, richfaces

Recently I notice that all action for submitting forms need to be executed twice to actually submit the values. Before this worked fine when I hard coded the resulting action path from my backing beans, but since I started to resolve all action path via the **faces-config** strange things has started to happen. One thing is that I need to press a submit button twice to fire the action, the browser fires the POST. I can see in *firebug* that two POST is fired and only the last one is processed by Glassfish.

Don know if this is side effect of the problem I experience. But many times when I do a *forward* the page losses CSS classes and things start to look ugly and some components (Richfaces - datatable) start to render badly. Actually I have to do *redirect* most of the time for things to render properly.

1. What can be the reason that I need to do two POST/submit before the Glassfish server will process the request ?
2. Why do I constantly need to redirect to make components (Richfaces) to render correctly ?

I use:

- Glassfish 3.1
- NetBeans 7.0.1
- Richfaces 4.0-final

Sample of my Faces-config;

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>CreateActivity</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/app_user/activity/Create.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>CreateActivityDetail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/app_user/activity/UpdateDetail.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Firebug log --

First POST (doesn't work when submitted)

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Faces-Request: partial/ajax
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/humis/faces/app_user/activity/List.xhtml
Content-Length: 430
Cookie: JSESSIONID=cd70a069ad528b3923bd52f12b1c 
        JSESSIONID=cbe0c977cf1c550f2a57cb4b334f; 
        treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:resources:jmsResources:jmsDestinationResources
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

First Response

```
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6), JSF/2.0
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 667
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 13:30:22 GMT
```

Second POST (the one that works)

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Faces-Request: partial/ajax
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/humis/faces/app_user/activity/List.xhtml
Content-Length: 494
Cookie: JSESSIONID=cd70a069ad528b3923bd52f12b1c; 
        JSESSIONID=cbe0c977cf1c550f2a57cb4b334f; 
        treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:resources:jmsResources:jmsDestinationResources
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Second Response

```
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6), JSF/2.0
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 145
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 13:30:44 GMT
```

Comment: Sometimes the POST is queued up that was supposed to happen previously, and the next action GET/POST will not be the current action until I press the button/commandlink again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like that you've mapped the `FacesServlet` on multiple URL-patterns and that in some way all the autogenerated URLs to CSS and JS resources become invalid. Doing some basic debugging and investigation of the `<link>` and `<script>` URLs in the JSF-generated HTML source and the HTTP traffic with for example [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) should give *a lot* of insights as to what exactly broke. You should have seen 404's for those CSS/JS resources.

As this trivial debugging information is missing in your question, I can't answer anything else than suggesting to trying to explicitly map the `FacesServlet` on a single URL pattern, e.g. `*.xhtml`.

Comment: Hi, Firebug don't issue any error during the request, for the CSS. Both my CSS has status 304 - Not modified. But my rich:dataTable don't render properly, seams to be after I done a redirect, but not sure. Maybe its the general navigation rule with the *. Tried to omit *, it means the same. But same result. Think I'll go back to hard code my resulting path again, just to make sure its nothing else. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Didn't help to hard code all the paths in the bean classes. The same as before. Any idea what to try next, maybe remove the domain1 or move everything into a new project?

Comment: BalusC; Added firebug debug info. To me it all looks very similar, but I haven't bean browsing/reading that many http logs.